# Mongoose - Control sort order of prop when undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Using mongoose, given a schema such as:

```js
const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
    },
    // more values
)
const Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema)
```

and a query such as:

```js
Item.find({}).sort('id')
```

Is there a way to specify how undefined values are sorted?

With my current data set, it appears to sort undefined values as `0` but I would prefer to sort undefined values as `Number.MAX_VALUE` so they appear at the end of the array instead of the start.

Comment: I think you should use two queries one where the `id` field exists and the other where it doesn't. And at last merge the response from both the queries.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That idea works well but I found that refactoring my schemas is a better solution for my use case. I can now safely set `Number.MAX_VALUE` as the default and sorting works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicate question is the same question as what I'm asking but is not how I solved the problem. I have changed my schema layout completely to allow me to specify a default value for the field I actually want to sort by. It seems like the best performing and easiest to visually parse solution until MongoDB supports null sorting options.

Here is a relevant [Issue on MongoDb Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24310)